# How to use same DB for two ddp connected applications

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, microservices

I have connected two meteor applications via DDP. I expected to get the DB data also on the second service application, but I don't get any data.
As both is running on server side I didn't do any subscription - which I think I don't have to in this example.

What am I doing wrong?

1. Starting main web application: `meteor` (which should load mongodb on port 3001)
2. Starting service application: `MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:3001/mydb meteor --port 3100`

*Web (main)*
**/server/main.js**

```
Examples = new Mongo.Collection('examples');
var serviceConn = DDP.connect("http://localhost:3100");
console.log(Examples.find().count()); // Returns 21
```

*Service 1*
**/server/main.js**

```
Examples = new Mongo.Collection('examples');
console.log(Examples.find().count()); // Returns 0 !
```

So why can't I get the collection data on the service application as it gives me 0 results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your service application:

```
const con = DDP.connect('http://localhost:3000');

Examples = new Mongo.Collection('examples', {
  connection: con,
});

console.log(Examples.find().count());
```

Remember to start your main application first